# What do you call someone who always puts blame on others?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, pejorative-language

No matter what had really happened, this person will always blame and find an appearing logical/thought out way/strategy to it that, fundamentally, it's the other person who was the cause for all the trouble AND everything else that came from this trouble as well and from the next and so on.

No (slang) words like "jerk", "*sshole" etc. please.

Comment: I'd be quite happy with [*He's a buck-passer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he's+a+buck-passer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but that seems to have surprisingly little currency.

Comment: .......... him.

Comment: Often, such a person is called a "manager" or a "politician".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Buck-passer relies on the person having had 'the buck' not just on dishing out blame (where the 'disher' is not to blame)

Comment: @Frank: I suppose much depends on whether the person concerned is already being blamed by others (and trying to *pass the buck, re-assign blame/responsibility* to someone else), or simply likes finding other people to blame regardless of whether he personally might otherwise be "in the frame". In the latter case, I'd just say he's a ***shit-stirrer***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite.

Answer (score 13):

***Blameshifter*** fits the bill.

> blameshifting
>
> Part of Speech:    n
>
> Definition:         the act of transferring responsibility for an error or problem to another;
>   also written blame shifting
>
> <sub>[Dictionary.com's 21st Century Lexicon](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226094701/http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blameshifting)</sub>

Comment: There is no such word from what I gather. Can anyone provide a dictionary reference for the word "blameshifter"?

Comment: Fair enough. I only documented blameshifting.

Comment: "blameshifter" is someone doing the blameshifting. :-)

Answer (score 10):

1. a *finger-pointer* - someone quick to divert attention or blame to someone else
2. *defensive* (though that's more general than just blaming others)

Answer (score 9):

A 'blamer'. It's slang for someone who always blames others. e.g. 'My mother was a blamer from  her early teens.' It tends to be applied to senior citizens. I don't make these things up. There seems to be a correlation between chronic intermeddlers (yentas) and chronic blamers. Often the blamer and the yenta are the same person.

Comment: Julian Teasure in a Ted talk entitled "How to speak so that people want to listen" coins the word "blamethrower" for that kind of people.

Answer (score 4):

That person is 'an adept at scapegoating'.

> scapegoat  (ˈskeɪpˌɡəʊt )
>
> Definitions
>
> noun
>
> 1. a person made to bear the blame for others
> 2. (Old Testament) a goat used in the ritual of Yom Kippur (Leviticus 16); it was symbolically laden with the sins of the Israelites and sent into the wilderness to be destroyed
>
> verb
>
> 1. (transitive) to make a scapegoat of
>
> Word Origin
>   C16: from escape + goat, coined by William Tyndale to translate Biblical Hebrew azāzēl (probably) goat for Azazel, mistakenly thought to mean 'goat that escapes'

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scapegoat

Answer (score 3):

I would say buck-passer is correct.

Anther class of idioms for someone who is difficult to blame involves variations around the word "teflon"

"He wears a teflon coat"

"He is made from teflon"

Because nothing (including blame) sticks to teflon. However, this does not necessarily involve  the subject shifting blame, they just somehow always escape blame somehow or other.

Comment: 'Buckpasser' doesn't work: it simply means to pass (usually work) onto other people, when you should do it yourself. It's not specific enough for blaming other for things. 'Blameshifter' works better, or 'rationalizer', although I don't know there's a single word for all the things the OP is trying to describe.

Comment: @Pete855217 I disagree, I think it means to pass blame or responsibility onto someone else. I have never even heard of the word "blameshifter" being used to describe someone - it sounds like a made up word. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buck-passer

Comment: -1 for Buckpasser, you can only be a buck-passer if you have the buck. Simply blaming someone isn't passing the buck. @Pete855217 I agree with aaa90201, buck-passing is passing blame onto someone else (when you have the blame on yourself). Where is it common to mean 'passing work that should do yourself to other people'?

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***blame artist***

> *Man has forever been a blame artist. We specialize in blaming others for our personal failures and even our individual irresponsibility. To the extent that even when a man has run down into a state no different from a carriage horse only good enough for haulage, he fails to recognize that. Instead he continues to see the other man plowing by hand as the slave. The hassle between the slave, servant and master is longstanding.*
>
> [Tug of War](http://www.abebooks.com/9781624193941/TUG-DILEMMA-CONTEMPORARY-SLAVE-SERVANT-1624193943/plp)

Comment: You could call someone that who manages to be appear *blameless* (not getting the blame).  But "artful dodger" is inappropriate for a person who always blames others.  In italian we call him a [*scaricabarile*](https://www.google.it/search?q=scaricabarile+in+inglese&oq=scarica+baril&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8350j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and here http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/S/scaricabarile.php

Comment: @Mari-LouA In French, we say "renvoyer la balle" http://www.wordreference.com/fren/renvoyer%20la%20balle

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps **rationalizer**? According to ODO, *[rationalize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rationalize#rationalize)* means

> Attempt to explain or justify (one’s own or another’s behavior or attitude) with logical, plausible reasons, even if these are not true or appropriate

Comment: But even if you're, without blame involved, try to to think logically about things you're a rationalizer as well, right? Isn't rationalizer easily to be confused with simply thinking logically without anything else, like blame?

Comment: While one of the meanings of *rationalize* is to think logically about something, it is more often used to describe a process that strains logic to find justification. It also can be used for tortured explanations even when there is no specific blame involved.

Comment: As someone has said, rationalization is the skin of reason stuffed with a lie.

Answer (score -1):

Some really good ones! Projection definitely but very clinical?

Shortest word for me, avoider. Of their own responsibility of their behaviour.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: It has context. People who project blame onto other people are avoiding something. Either taking responsibility for their own fault or behaviour. Projection is a more clinical term for it. There are also some very long explanations I was simply adding a short alternative.

Answer (score -4):

Well, unfortunately, to so cleverly dodge responsibility/blame AND effectively shift it onto someone else, (and let's just call it like it is without the sugarcoating - that's lying; the worst kind), is a component of the group of behaviors associated with sociopathy - especially when this behavior is the norm, (chronic), and not the exception.  It is plausible, even likely, this person is a sociopath.  At the very least, he/she is 'borderline'.