# Idiom or phrase associated with a person who blame others for his or her fault?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

Is there an idiom or phrase associated with a person who can't do some work or something but he or she blames something or somebody else?

Comment: How about "generous with a fault"?

Comment: 'Moaning Minnie.' a habitual grumbler (is equally applied to men or women) http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/248700.html

Comment: possible duplicate of  [What do you call someone who always puts blame on others?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185835/what-do-you-call-someone-who-always-puts-blame-on-others)

Comment: It's widely know as "[the blame game](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/fulfillment-any-age/201509/5-reasons-we-play-the-blame-game)"

Comment: BTW, you can use "blame gamer" for the person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[A bad workman blames his tools](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+bad+workman+blames+his+tools)***,  might fit the bill:

> - something that you say when someone blames the objects they are using for their own mistakes.
>
>   - *'This oven burns everything.' 'You know what they say, a bad workman blames his tools.'*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Comment: It might were it not for the fact that someone replaced the usual *poor* by *bad*…

Comment: But blaming your tools is different from blaming another person.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, such a person is ***irresponsible***.  In a phrase, such a person "***has no sense of responsibility***."

Irresponsible means not responsible.

Responsible is defined by Merriam Webster as:

"2a  able to answer for one's conduct and obligations: trustworthy
 2b  able to choose for oneself between right and wrong"

Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary defines responsibility as:
 "....Accountability, also moral accountability, as the *responsibilities* of parenthood; Reliability...."

You might say "If you want the job done, and done right and on time, do **not** ask X; he is completely irresponsible."  Or ".... do **not** ask X; he has no sense of responsibility."

In looking up definitions for the phrase, I find "awareness of obligations" (e.g., The Free Dictionary).  However, as I have always used it, the phrase goes further: the person is not only aware, but cares.

Thus, I like the example quoted in Philiosiblog:  "The most important thing is to have a sense of responsibility, commitment, and concern for each of our fellow human beings."   Dalai Lama

Answer (score 0):

A "scapegoat" is someone whom someone, or multiple people, wrongly blame for something going wrong.  You can use it as a verb too.

(It originates for a primitive ritual in which everyone symbolically piles their sins and problems on a real goat, who was sacrificed to cleanse the community of evil)

Answer (score 0):

To find fault with someone or something. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/find+fault