# Equivalent proverb in English for falsely blaming other things for your lack of ability

Tags: translation, proverbs, hindi

There's a proverb in Hindi which literally translates to:

> (He/she/You/they) doesn't know how to dance and falsely blames the
>   floor for being crooked/broken/skewed

What is an equivalent English proverb for this? Obviously, it need not be about dancing as long as the point is conveyed, which is:

- the target doesn't have the skill/ability/knowledge for the dance.
- the floor is perfectly fine and it shouldn't be blamed.

EDIT: I've been forced to add this bit to convey that the idiom 'A bad workman blames his tools' doesn't fit in this context.

The workman blaming his tools would be like a dancer blaming his shoes. A dancer blaming the floor would be like the workman blaming the floor or something that disturbed him while working or even the weather. Hope that can convey the difference.

Comment: I believe your question has already been answered here:
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/265698/254919
Just be warned that this is not a commonly used proverb, and I do not believe there is any commonly used proverb that matches your description.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KumaAra, but in the very scenario I've specified re: the dancer, would 'A bad workman blames his tools' really fit here? I don't believe it would.

Comment: A dancer who is bad at dancing blames the floor for making him bad at dancing.  "It's not my fault I messed up the dance! This floor is bumpy!" Likewise, a bad workman will blame his tools for his workmanship being poor.  "It's not my fault your table looks crooked, the jointer I used is crooked!"  Both involve someone not skilled at the task that blames some outside object for their poor performance.  And in both cases, the floor/tools are actually perfectly fine.  It is in fact the dancer/workman who is just unskilled at the task.

Comment: KumaAra, you seem to be first suggesting *A poor workman blames his tools* isn't common usage, then commending it. I wasn't counting yet I'd bet I've heard it several times in each and every one of my 62 years. I do think it is less common now than it was generations ago but that's a different thing, isn't it?